# Can read only access be granted websphere 7 admin console?

Tags: websphere-7

How can I grant read only access to the admin console for websphere 7 what are the settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the user to the appropriate Administrative role. In this case, you probably need to map the user to the "monitor" role.

**Monitor-** An individual or group that uses the monitor role has the least amount of privileges. A monitor can complete the following tasks:

- View the WebSphere Application Server configuration.
- View the current state of the Application Server

.
**To make the change using admin console:**

- Login to the admin console as Administrator user.
- Click on "Users and Groups"
- Click on "Administrative user roles"
- Click on "Add" Select the Role from the list and search the user who should be assigned this role. Move the user to "Mapped to role".
- Save the configuration
  and the user should be able to login in with assigned privileges.

More information about Administrative roles at http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rsec_adminroles.html